# Why Can I not Get the reference of an object from another class in a namespace c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to open a connection to a database and I have used a configuration string to connect and I've instantiated the sqlConnection object. I would like to be able to use this reference in a new classes method. Why am I not able to achieve this? Why does it say "this class cannot be inherited"?

```
namespace sqlLibrary
{
    public class sqlStuff
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SurplusConnectionString"].ConnectionString);  

    }

    public class commands : sqlStuff
    {
        public void executeQuery()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = myConnection; --> Not able to get reference from sql stuff class? 
        } 
    }    
}
```

Comment: I doubt that's all it says.  Show us the entire error message.  All relevant info.

Answer (score 7):

By default, fields (and other class members) have `private` access modifier. Thus they are not visible in child classes. You should explicitly specify `protected` visibility

```
 protected SqlConnection myConnection
```

See [Accessibility Levels (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels)